# Action Mailer 'undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Im getting an error when trying to send an email. Not to sure why but here is my code in my controller and mailer

Here is my controller code below

```
class Invitation::InvitesController < ApplicationController

def invite_provider
      @patient = Patient.find_by_id(invite_params[:invitable_id])
      recipient = params[:email]
      InviteMailer.provider_invite(recipient).deliver_now
      flash[:success] = "An email has been sent to"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end

end
```

Here is my mailer code

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
def provider_invite(recipient)
    @recipient = recipient
    mail(
      to: recipient[:email],
      subject: I18n.t('provider_invite_subject')
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: your email params is empty

Answer (score 1):

At the call to `mail`, in the `to` option, you're basically sending `params[:email][:email]`. I don't think that's what you want.

```
recipient = params[:email]
```

and then

```
to: recipient[:email],
```

Answer (score 0):

You have called `InviteMailer.provider_invite(recipient)` where recipient is `email` inside controller.

You can change in controller,

```
InviteMailer.provider_invite(email: recipient)
```

and then,

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def provider_invite(attr)
    @recipient = attr[:email]
    mail(
      to: @recipient,
      subject: I18n.t('provider_invite_subject')
    )
  end
end
```

And error is due to your params o not have email key, so recipient is nil passed through controller

Comment: Thanks! That got the error to go away but it's not sending to the email i entered in. This is the output of what I am getting 'From: notgoingtosay@gmail.com
To: email' <-----